# Hide Program From Volume Mixer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've written a program that loops a tiny, silent .wav file for the purpose of preventing the soundcard in my Surface Pro 3 from going into power save mode. I've managed to make the form not show up in the alt-tab menu, taskbar and not show up under the "Applications" heading in the task manager. However, the program still shows up in the Volume Mixer program. Is there anyway to make it not show up?

Comment: What is an "SP3"? Can't you edit the sound card properties to disable energy saving modes so you don't need this workaround altogether? I can't find a way to hide applications in the Volume Mixer, if an application has an audio session open it gets shown there, as far as my research shows.

Comment: Surface Pro 3. It's a semi-common problem - when no sound is playing, any device plugged into the headphone jack will make a weird 'popping' noise.